# Run tests in popup

Tags: textmate, textmate2

In TextMate 1 when I do cmd+R in tests - it opens a popup. In TextMate 2 it shows the running tests in the footer panel.

How can I get the popup back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at these release notes below:

http://tm2tips.tumblr.com/post/14373351819/8949-released (The first point)

From the textmate blog:

http://wiki.macromates.com/FAQ/TextMate2ExpertPreferences

So the command should be

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview htmlOutputPlacement bottom
```

or

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview htmlOutputPlacement right
```

depending on where you want the window. (The default value is "window").

Comment: Is there a way to keep the cursor's focus in the editor window? Or a keyboard shortcut to jump between them?